# FreeBSD pre-mount script for gnop device?

Tags: freebsd, mount

How do I run a script in FreeBSD before filesystems are mounted?

I want to install a gnop device and mount it (no, not for ZFS). Is there any canonical place where I can put a `gnop create ...`?

Answer (score 1):

Create an rc script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

# PROVIDE: gnop disks
# BEFORE: fsck

. /etc/rc.subr

name="gnop"
start_cmd="${name}_start"
stop_cmd=

gnop_start()
{
    local disk="/dev/da1"
    /sbin/gnop create -S 4096 "$disk" || err 1 "Creating gnop on $disk failed"
}

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

where /dev/ada1
This could be extended to created multiple nop devices based on a configuration in `rc.conf`.